# WPF, calling method with parameters in XAML's class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stack-overflow, objectdataprovider

I have an `ObjectDataProvider` in my XAML that references a method in my `Window`-deriving class.  That is, I have `NewForm.xaml.cs` with class `NewForm` and the `ObjectDataProvider` in `NewForm.xaml` is referencing a method in `NewForm`.  Currently, with the following XAML, I get a stack overflow error because the `NewForm` constructor keeps getting called over and over again:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.NewForm" ...>
<Window.Resources>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="getTeamName"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:NewForm}"
                    MethodName="GetTeamName">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:Int32>-1</sys:Int32>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

I'm guessing it's because the `ObjectType` is set to `NewForm`, so it loads `NewForm` to load my application, but then it has to create a new instance of `NewForm` in order to call `GetTeamName`, but the constructor calls `InitializeComponent` which creates a new `NewForm` which has to create a new `NewForm` to call `GetTeamName`...  It actually crashes Visual Studio 2010 every time.

Anyway, what I'm asking is do I have to define methods that my XAML calls via `ObjectDataProvider`s in some other class?  Or can I somehow use `ObjectDataProvider` with a method defined in my XAML's class?  Or to call a method in my XAML's class, should I be using some other XAML besides `ObjectDataProvider`?  It doesn't seem like I can put my C# method in another class since it uses `TryFindResource` to get an `XmlDataProvider` from my XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem here is that `ObjectDataProvider` always creates a new instance of whatever object it's created for.  So yes, it will create an instance of the `NewForm` class, whose constructor will instantiate another `ObjectDataProvider` that creates an instance of the `NewForm` class, and then it's turtles all the way down.

But the thing is, `ObjectDataProvider` is really just a way to declare create objects and call methods on them in XAML, so that you don't have to do it in code-behind.  Since you're already creating the object in code-behind, avoiding code-behind isn't benefiting you.  So just have the method that creates the object also add it to the window's resource dictionary:

```
// this method no longer needs to return anything, so you can change its signature
private void GetTeamName()
{
    // code that creates the object goes here.
    // and now, instead of "return myObject", do this:
    Resources.Add("getTeamOName");
}
```